# guess who game in java variables errors

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Cluedo2 {

private static Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.print("Pensez a un personnage : Mlle Rose, ");
    System.out.println("le Professeur Violet, le Colonel Moutarde,");
    System.out.println("le Reverend Olive ou Mme Leblanc.\n");

    System.out.print("Est-ce que votre personnage est un homme ? ");
    System.out.print("(true : oui, false : non) ");
    boolean homme = clavier.nextBoolean();
    if(homme){
        System.out.print("Votre personnage a-t-il des moustaches ? ");

        boolean moustaches = clavier.nextBoolean();


        System.out.print("Votre personnage porte-t-il un chapeau ? ");
        boolean chapeau = clavier.nextBoolean();
    }

    else{
    System.out.print("Votre personnage porte-t-il des lunettes ? ");
    boolean lunettes = clavier.nextBoolean();
    }




    System.out.print("==> Le personnage auquel vous pensez est ");

    if (homme) {
        /*******************************************
         * Completez le programme a partir d'ici.
         *******************************************/
            if(moustaches){
                System.out.println("le Colonel Moutarde");
            }
            else if(chapeau){
                System.out.println("le Professeur Violet");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("le Reverend Olive");
            }
    }
    else {

        if(lunettes){
        System.out.println("Mme Leblanc");  
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Mlle Rose");
        }


        /*******************************************
         * Ne rien modifier apres cette ligne.
         *******************************************/
    }

    System.out.println();
}
}
```

I get this Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    moustaches cannot be resolved to a variable
    chapeau cannot be resolved to a variable
    lunettes cannot be resolved to a variable

at Cluedo2.main(Cluedo2.java:41)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your variables inside an `if` statement, so they will not exist outside this code block. Move the declarations out of the `if` block if you need to be able to access them later in your code:

```
boolean moustaches = false;
boolean chapeau = false;
if(homme){
    System.out.print("Votre personnage a-t-il des moustaches ? ");
    moustaches = clavier.nextBoolean();
    System.out.print("Votre personnage porte-t-il un chapeau ? ");
    chapeau = clavier.nextBoolean();
}
```

Comment: the resault is always false in the second if condition